# Glitch with Maximum value of NumericUpDown C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have set the NumericUpDowns Maximum Values to 100 (design part) but if the user presses a number that is longer than 3 digits (for example 5555) it shows up as 5100. Should I set the maximum value to an event or is there another way I can limit the user entering 4 digits numbers?
[Fourth NumericUpDown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q6MW.png)

Comment: It's not a glitch, or maybe it is. It will just automatically change to the maximum value once the cursor left the NumericUpDown, so I suggest to create a KeyPress event to check if the length of the control exceeds the Maximum Value if you want to stop this from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the following code to the `keyup event`:

```
private void numericUpDown1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    decimal tmp = Convert.ToDecimal(numericUpDown1.Value.ToString());
    if (tmp >= 100)
    {
        numericUpDown1.Value = 100;
    }
}
```

After we set the maximum value under normal circumstances, it will only judge after `enter` or lose `focus`.

When you add it to the `keydown event`. It will become `5100`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works! I tried it with KeyDown and KeyPress  event but It only changed the value after I removed the cursor.